# How to transform the control rig of an unreal engine metahuman using the remote control plugin and python?

Tags: python, remote-control, unreal-engine5

I am developing a motion tracking system using python and OpenCV. I currently have the capabilities to track markers to get their rotation and translation.

I have recently tried to use the UE remote control plugin to control objects within my scene from an external python program. I have successfully made my motion tracking technology move entire objects around, but I am now wanted to move only specific bones of an object (specifically a metahuman). For example, I may want to rotate the shoulder.

There seems to be a lack of documentation surrounding the remote control plugin, so I am struggling to finish my motion tracking system. Documentation can be found [***here***](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/ProductionPipelines/ScriptingAndAutomation/WebControl/Endpoints/).

My current code is:

```
to_send = {
            "objectPath" : "/Game/" + path_level + ":PersistentLevel." + name_actor,        #Path to object
            "functionName" : "SetActorLocation",                                            #Function to transform actor
            "parameters" : {
                    "NewLocation" : {"X" : X, "Y" : Z, "Z" : Y},                            #Position
                    "bSweep" : True                                                        
                },
            "generateTransaction" : True                                                    #Allow for the action to be undone
        }

    response = requests.put("http://" + ip + ":" + port + "/remote/object/call", json=to_send)    #Send data to Unreal engine server
```

I really hope someone can help me. I am using UE5 and want to control the specific bone/s of a metahuman using python over LAN.

Thank you in advance, SolveItPlanet

Comment: Hi, I have found this playlist on youtube, though I haven't yet tried it to check if it works. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnFVXCUAWlE&list=PLCFP4Gs-mIbxZ0fJUaqIEaD0tAvFTQ8pl